# Recursive AJAX calls get cancelled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page showing log files which I want to give the user the ability to select and delete. The deletion is done through an AJAX request where the ID of each log-for-deletion is sent via the parameters.

The problem is that there are instances where there are hundreds of logs and in these cases the AJAX request seems to fail. I assume because there is just too much data sent via the parameters. I have tried breaking the AJAX request into parts, but only the first request is sent, afterwards all other requests are shown in Chorme as "cancelled". Following is my code:

```js
var logFiles = [];

function deleteLogBatch() {
  if (logFiles.length == 0) 
    return false;
    
  if (logFiles.length > 10) 
    var elements = 10;
  else 
    var elements = logFiles.length;

  var params = 'action=deletelog';

  for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    params += '&lf' + i + '=' + escape(logFiles.shift());
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './ajax/logs.php',
    data: params,
    success: function(response) {
      checkResponse(response);
      deleteLogBatch();
    }
  });
}

$('body').on('click', '#confirm-log-delete', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('.select-log').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      logFiles.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }
  });

  deleteLogBatch();
}
```

Any help as to why this is happening and what is the proper way of doing this would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to split the requests; you're not sending that much data. When a bulk request fails, check the response in the browser console. Checking the server side logs would also be a good idea. It's unlikely to be caused by too much data in the request, but a server side logic problem instead.

Comment: Again, there hundreds or even thousands of log files in some requests...

Comment: So? Whether you send one big request or lots of little ones (which is a worse idea) the problem is still not in your JS logic, but the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: './ajax/logs.php',
async: true,
data: params,
success: function(response) {
  checkResponse(response);
  deleteLogBatch();
}
```

});

It will not wait to previous ajax call